# I/O initialisation. Curious for the reason PIC16F18877

Tags: pic, c, assembly

For the initialisation of an I/O in the pic the datasheet indicates to clear set the TRIS correctly and clear both PORT and LAT bits. I thought I understood why and the program works. When looking at the disassembly however the PORT clearing and LAT clearing generate the same instructions. I did not look further but I think that the PORT bits are cleared as a result of the LAT bits clearing.

Is there a specific reason that the datasheet (asm) indicated to clear both PORT and LAT and in C it boils down to one action only on LAT.

C code example lead both to identical asm after compilation:

```
PORTAbits.RA0 = 0;
LATAbits.LATA0 = 0;
```

Comment: What is the C code and what is the assembly generated?

Comment: Samples of C included

Comment: Still, it is incomplete without the assembly generated.. BTW, can you look around your headers ans see the exact definition of `PORTA` and `LATA` ? Could it be that they are just the same register?

Comment: Reason found. In the lib used there was a macro with a typo leading to this behaviour. After correcting this both registers are handled the same way as in the specsheet

Comment: Is it the vendor provided macro or some homebrew/thirparty?

Comment: third party. Happy anyway